# NodeJS - Main file not receiving return of a lookupService inside a function

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a file called 'myinternet_utils.js' and the following function:

```js
exports.hasInternet = function () {

 require('dns').lookupService('8.8.8.8', 53, function (err, hostname, service) {
  return hostname;
 });

};
```

I also have a file called 'server.js', where I have this piece of code:

```js
var ieUtils_ = require('./myinternet_utils.js');

console.log( ieUtils_.hasInternet() );
```

The 'console.log' prints 'undefined'.

Why am I not getting the output of the function hasInternet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the function you are using is asynchronous. Also your function does not actually return anything, so even if it was synchronous you would still get `undefined`. Try this instead, using promises:

```
exports.hasInternet = function () {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        require('dns').lookupService('8.8.8.8', 53, function (err, hostname, service) {
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(hostname);
        });
    });

};
```

and in the main file

```
var ieUtils_ = require('./myinternet_utils.js');

ieUtils_.hasInternet().then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to give it a try using your suggestion. However, for the record, the function lookupService actually returns 'hostname'.
See: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookupservice_address_port_callback

Comment: Thank you mr Bouchlis, the Promise works like a charm =) You are a life saver, sir.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance @FabricioGanzert